# Split a string containing arrow characters

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am using the Github API to load comments into a page and when I load comments which have come from email they are formatted with arrows as below:

```
'Comment↵↵On 13 November 2015 at 16:50...'
```

I want to remove the second part to just get the comment but can't seem to do this using the javascript split method, I have tried the following:

```
comment.split('&#8626;');
comment.split('&#8629;');
```

as according to these HTML codes: http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php

And also tried using Regex:

```
comment.split(/&[^;]*;/);
```

Neither of these seems to be working however.

Does anyone know how I should go about splitting a string with arrows like these?

Many Thanks

Comment: `'Comment↵↵On 13 November 2015 at 16:50...'.split('↵↵')`

Comment: I believe Azzis answer might be the correct one, but have you checked, what characters are actually retrieved? Its not about what it looks like or is displayed (arrows, supposedly) but what is there. You wont be able to detect an actual "↵" by looking for its entity code, be it unicode or html enities or whatever.

Comment: I don't fully understand how unicode, regex, etc. works but you are indeed correct that `comment.split('↵')` doesn't work Stefan.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the new line characters try this.

```
comment = comment.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
```

Comment: Actually, the `/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g` regex can be contracted to `/[\r\n]+/g`. However, I do not think it is `replace` that is necessary here.

Comment: This works (yes with split rather than replace), thanks!